# JSON Date field Error

Tags: webservices, rest, date

I have the JSON string below that is being sent to a Salesforce Webservice:

```
{"Opportunity":
{"Id":"006g000000IiM5z",
"Appraisal_Date__c":"2019-11-22"}
```

I serialize the request into a Map and am trying to get the Date field value but get an error from Apex when trying to send from Postman: '?

> System.TypeException: Invalid date: 2019-11-22

I've tried `date.valueof` and casting using `(date)` but no luck with either. Not sure why the below code will not work (all other field types work fine):

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
Map<String, Object> oppMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(requestBody);

Opportunity o = new Opportunity();

if ((Object)oppMap.get('Appraisal_Date__c') != null) { 
    o.Appraisal_Date__c = Date.valueof(oppMap.get('Appraisal_Date__c'));
}
```

Comment: What's your user's locale? Try using Date.parse instead of Date.valueOf - just keep in mind locale restrictions

Comment: Time Zone (GMT-05:00) Eastern Standard Time (America/New_York)
Locale English (United States)

Tried 'o.Appraisal_Date__c = Date.parse(oppMap.get('Appraisal_Date__c'));' but got the error 'Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void parse(Object) from the type Date'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not casting the object returned by (Map)JSON.deserializeUntyped(requestBody). Change to the following:

```
o.Appraisal_Date__c = Date.parse((String)oppMap.get('Appraisal_Date__c'));
```

Comment: That did it, thanks so much Glen!

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
Opportunity o = (Opportunity) JSON.deserialize(requestBody,Opportunity.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out.